# Socialengine - How to add custom module to layout editor

Tags: php, layout, module, editor, socialengine

I've made a few modules within my socialengine application however I was wondering how do I add these to the layout editor (`root/admin/content`) so that I can add widgets to these pages?

Comment: Why was this down voted? At least give me a comment so I can make sufficient edits. Jesus

Comment: it was probably downvoted because there is no code.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the widget in layout editor by adding setting in ***content.php*** file.

Answer (score 1):

We recommend adding your widget via the Package Manager which should help take care of the rest. For more information, please see in the Developer SDK section: http://support.socialengine.com/questions/180/Admin-Panel-Manage-Packages-Plugins

Answer (score 1):

You should create a page first from layout editor.DO NOT GIVE any page URL in edit page info section.Leave the page without URL.Most important, add the content widget to your page and save it.

Now, you have a fresh page which does n't have url set.Create a module and either install it or paste it in your application/modules directory. Now, open your database and find the table
"engine4_core_pages" and click on insert and set the name field with your modulename_controller_action.

Comeback to your module and open index controller and put whatever code you want to in index action and just add a simple code to view this in your page,"

```
$this->_helper->content
            //   ->setNoRender()
            ->setEnabled()
```

You are done.You can set the route from your modules manifest.php inside settings 
folder.

Hope this will help.

http://bloffin.blogspot.in/ for more...